About Bad Dreams
Assalamu Alaikum Wa Rahmatullah.
I’ve been pondering over a nightmare for the past few days. Elders often say that nightmares should not be shared with others, and it’s better to keep them a secret.
However, it feels like this nightmare is eating me up inside day by day. That’s why I wish to seek guidance from respected scholars.
It was the middle of the night, around 2 AM, the last part of the night.
Two days ago, I had this dream. I saw myself rising up into the sky, and suddenly, I died. Darkness surrounded everything.
But suddenly, amidst all that, there was a "Dream Light" in the room. Immediately after, in that faint light, I woke up and realized, Alhamdulillah, I’m alive.
I was deeply shaken by this dream.
Please gimme the righteous islamic solution for the dream, tell the reason behind it...

Questions about the interpretation of you dreams are off-topic. See Should dream interpretation questions be on-topic?.
